# Запустить онлайн игру на node.js и вебсокетах

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер, сокет

Есть репозиторий (не мой) https://github.com/dwcares/realchess
В котором написан скрипт онлайн шахмат.

Но проблема в том, что там используется node.js, с которым я не работал, а поставить его на локальный сервер нужно уже сегодня. Поискал похожие случаи в интернете, но в итоге понял, что stackoverflow справится с этим лучше.

Опишите, пожалуйста, пошаговую инструкцию как запустить этот сайт на своей машине.

P.s. в основном работаю с open server на виндоус, но если потребуется могу подключить LAMP

Comment: Устанавливаете nodejs, клонируете проект, устанавливаете зависимости,  запускаете проект командой node  app.js

Comment: Как установить зависимости?

Comment: Командой "npm i"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По порядку:

1. Клонируем репозиторий `git clone
   git@github.com:dwcares/realchess.git`
2. Переходим в папку с проектом  `cd realchess`
3. Устанавливаем зависимости `npm i` или `yarn`
4. Запускаем приложение `node .` (Данная команда равносильна `node
   ./app.js` так как `app.js` указан как `main` file в `package.json` данного проекта
5. Переходим на http://localhost:3000/ и играем в шахматы ♕

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]